# Delphi - Cannot cast TVirtualInterface to base interface of virtualized interface

Tags: delphi, casting, rtti

Howdey,

I am using TVirtualInterface to implement some interfaces. Those interfaes represent Keys that can be found in a DB. I generate the interface definitions with a custom made code generator. For example :

```
// Base code 

IKey = interface
  function KeyFields : string;
  function KeyValues : Variant;
  function GetKeyValue(const aKeyName : string) : Variant;
  procedure SetKeyValue(const aKeyName : string; Value : Variant);
end;

// Generated code

ITable1Key = interface(IKey)
end;

ITable1Key1 = interface(ITable1Key)
  procedure SetField1(const Value : string);
  function GetField1 : string;
  property Field1 : string read GetField1 write SetField1;
end;

ITable1Key2 = interface(ITable1Key)
  procedure SetField1(const Value : string);
  function GetField1 : string;
  property Field1 : string read GetField1 write SetField1;
  procedure SetField2(const Value : string);
  function GetField2 : string;
  property Field2 : string read GetField1 write SetField1;
end;

// Other generated declarations
```

I use the TVirtualInterface to implement each IKey interface instead of implementing them one by one.

Though, in my TVirtualInterface :

```
TKey = TVirtualInterface
public
  constructor Create(aType : PTypeInfo);
  function Cast : IKey;
end;

TKey<T : IKey>
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce;
  function Cast : T;
end;


constructor TKey.Create(aType : PTypeInfo)
begin
  inherited Create(aType, aHandlerMethod);
end;

function TKey.Cast;
var
  pInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  pInfo := TypeInfo(IKey);
  if QueryInterface(GetTypeData(pInfo).Guid, Result) <> 0 then
  begin
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Sorry, TKey is unable to cast %s to its interface ', [string(pInfo.Name)]);
  end;
end;

constructor TKey<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(TypeInfo(T));
end;

function TKey<T>.Cast;
var
  pInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  pInfo := TypeInfo(T);
  if QueryInterface(GetTypeData(pInfo).Guid, Result) <> 0 then
  begin
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Sorry, TKey<T> is unable to cast %s to its interface ', [string(pInfo.Name)]);
  end;
end;
```

I have no problem casting the TKey virtual interface to the T type using the TKey.Cast method, though TKey.Cast returns a Interface not supported error.

I checked in System.Rtti for the part that wasn't working the way I wanted it to :

```
function TVirtualInterface.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if iid = FIID then
  begin
    _AddRef;
    Pointer(Obj) := @VTable;
    Result := S_OK;
  end
  else
    Result := inherited
end;
```

Now, how can I force the TVirtualInterface to cast itself to a IID that is a parent interface of the FIID field ? Do I have to create another instance of the TVirtualInterface for the IKey interface ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing `TVirtualInterface`.  It is just an RTTI helper, you should not be deriving from it at all.  You should be deriving from `TInterfacedObject` instead.

Also, both of your `TKey` classes are ignoring the `PTypeInfo` that is passed to the constructor.  The non-Generic `TKey.Cast()` is always querying for `IKey` only, never a descendant interface.  And the Generic `TKey<T>.Cast` is always re-querying `T`'s RTTI to get its IID.  So get rid of the `PTypeInfo` in the constructor, it is wasted.

Since the non-Generic `TKey` is just a base class that doesn't actually implement any derived interfaces at all, `TKey.QueryInterface()` will always fail for any interface other than `IKey` itself.  At least the Generic `TKey` can query a derived interface.

Your `Cast` functions are redundant anyway, since you can use the `as` operator, or the `SysUtils.Supports()` function, to cast one interface to another.  These are the preferred methods, not using `QueryInterface()` manually.

In any case, your interfaces are missing IIDs in their declarations, so you can't cast between interfaces anyway.

Try something more like this:

```
// Base code 

IKey = interface
  ['{D6D212E0-C173-468C-8267-962CFC3FECF5}']
  function KeyFields : string;
  function KeyValues : Variant;
  function GetKeyValue(const aKeyName : string) : Variant;
  procedure SetKeyValue(const aKeyName : string; Value : Variant);
end;

// Generated code

ITable1Key = interface(IKey)
  ['{B8E44C43-7248-442C-AE1B-6B9E426372C1}']
end;

ITable1Key1 = interface(ITable1Key)
  ['{0C86ECAA-A8E7-49EB-834F-77DE62BE1D28}']
  procedure SetField1(const Value : string);
  function GetField1 : string;
  property Field1 : string read GetField1 write SetField1;
end;

ITable1Key2 = interface(ITable1Key)
  ['{82226DE9-221C-4268-B971-CD72617C19C7}']
  procedure SetField1(const Value : string);
  function GetField1 : string;
  property Field1 : string read GetField1 write SetField1;
  procedure SetField2(const Value : string);
  function GetField2 : string;
  property Field2 : string read GetField1 write SetField1;
end;

// Other generated declarations
```

```
type
  TKey = class(TInterfacedObject, IKey)
  public
    function Cast : IKey;
    // IKey methods...
  end;

  TKey<T : IKey> = class(TInterfacedObject, IKey, T)
  public
    function Cast : T;
  end;

  TTable1Key = class(TKey, IKey, ITable1Key)
  end;

  TTable1Key1 = class(TTable1Key, IKey, ITable1Key, ITable1Key1)
  public
    // ITable1Key1 methods...
  end;

  TTable1Key2 = class(TTable1Key, IKey, ITable1Key, ITable1Key2)
  public
    // Table1Key2 methods...
  end;

// and so on ...

function TKey.Cast: IKey;
begin
  if not Supports(Self, IKey, Result) then
    raise Exception.Create('Sorry, unable to cast to IKey');
end;

function TKey<T>.Cast: T;
begin
  if not Supports(Self, GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T)).Guid, Result) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Sorry, unable to cast to %s', [string(TypeInfo(T).Name)]);
end;

// other class methods as needed ...
```

Also note how the derived classes have to repeat the interfaces implemented by their base classes.  That is a known Delphi limitation.  Derived classes do not inherit base class interfaces.  Each class has to explicitly specify the interfaces it implements, even if the actual implementation is in a base class.

Comment: Is this "limitation" a new problem ?  In Delphi you always had to declare the implementation of inherited interfaces where a class directly implemented both a derived interface and any base interface(s), but interface implementation is (or used to be) inherited from a base class where that base class itself declared the implementation of the interface(s).  The only 'problem' was if the base class implemented the methods of an interface without actually declaring the implementation of the interface itself.  Unless my memory is playing tricks (I don't currently have Delphi to hand to test).

Comment: @Deltics: "*Is this "limitation" a new problem ?*" - no, it has always been there. The implementation of an interface's methods can be inherited from base class to derived classes through normal polymorphism as expected, but the interface has to be specified in each derived class declaration in order to appear in each class's internal interface table so `TObject.GetInterface()` (and by extension, `IInterface.QueryInterface()`, the `is` and `as` operators, `SysUtils. Supports()` etc) can see it. Not ideal, and C++ doesn't have that limitation.